# A question about freeness of a certain class of abelian groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Lets call an abelian group $G$, to be semi-free (or **SF**) if every nonzero subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times H$ for some abelian group $H$.

Is every semi-free group, a free group? If not, does there exist a good characterization of this class of abelian groups?

Comment: For a module over a ring $R$, this means: module $M$ such that each nonzero submodule $N$ has $\mathrm{Hom}(N,R)\neq 0$. A sufficient condition is to be residually free, or equivalently residually-$R$, i.e., embeddable into $R^X$ for some set $X$. Since $\mathbf{Z}^X$ is indeed not free for $X$ infinite (as indicated in [Jeremy Rickard's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/460498/14094)), one can alternatively ask whether there is a non-residually-free module with this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Baer-Specker group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baer%E2%80%93Specker_group) $B$, the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, is semi-free but not free.

It is semi-free, because for any nonzero element $x\in B$ there is some projection $\pi:B\to\mathbb{Z}$ onto one of the direct factors for which $\pi(x)\neq0$, so if $K$ is any nonzero subgroup of $B$ there is a nonzero homomorphism $\varphi:K\to\mathbb{Z}$, and so $K\cong\ker(\varphi)\oplus\operatorname{im}(\varphi)\cong\ker(\varphi)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you please give your proof why this group is semi-free?

Comment: @Mostafa I've added a proof.